# G++ gives cryptic error messages, some pointer issue

Tags: c++, arrays, g++

I'm new to C++ and struggling trying to make multi-file programs work.  I had a Graph library functioning in C, and I am running into trouble converting it to C++.  My biggest problem from g++ is this error message,

```
error: no match for âoperator=â in â*(((Graph*)this)->Graph::adj +
((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)i) * 32ul))) = (operator
new(32u), (<statement>, ((List*)<anonymous>)))â
```

Here is the section of my Graph.cpp code it is complaining about:

```
Graph::Graph(int n){
    order = n;
    size = 0;
    source = NIL;
    color = static_cast<char*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(char)));
    distance = static_cast<int*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int)));
    parent = static_cast<int*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int)));
    adj = static_cast<List*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(List*)));
    discover = static_cast<int*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int)));
    finish = static_cast<int*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int)));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        color[i] = 'w';
        distance[i] = INF;
        parent[i] = NIL;
        adj[i] = new List();
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using a bit of a hybrid between C and C++, but a pure C++ implementation doesn't work either.  Further down in my file, I constantly get the error " error: base operand of â->â has non-pointer type âListâ", and I think it all comes from how I'm declaring.  I've looked around on here and have found other people complaining of this error, but I haven't seen it help with assigning to an array.  Help would be awesome, because except for this I know it all works.

Comment: how do you define `adj`?

Comment: And the class body for `Graph` is?

Comment: What type are 'color', 'distance', 'parent' and 'adj' declared as?

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `Graph::adj` to be of type `List*` (`adj[i]` is the same as doing `*(adj+i)`), and dereferencing a pointer to type `T` will yield a value of type `T`, ie. the type of `adj[i]` is `List`.

If you really want to do what you are trying to do declare `Graph::adj` as `List**`, that way it will be a pointer to a bunch of pointers to `List`, not a pointer to a bunch of `List`s.

---

**I don't understand, what the heck are you trying to say?**

You are trying to assign a `List*` (returned by `new List`) to a variable of type `List`.

```
struct List {
  // ... 
};

List ** adj = static_cast<List**> (
  std::calloc (10, sizeof (List*))
);

/* error

   List * adj = static_cast<List*> (
     std::calloc (10, sizeof (List*))
   );

*/

adj[0] = new List;
```

---

**Okay, I get you.. but there must be a better way to solve this issue?**

There sure is, use what c++ provides you with and ditch your old C habits.

```
List * adj = new List [10]; // create an array of 10 List

adj[i].member_of_List ...;  // example

delete [] adj;              // free up allocated memory when you are done
```

Comment: It was the double pointer thing.  I keep forgetting that I have to declare them that way, since Java was my first language I'm not used to having to do all the extra pointer stuff.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2309865 don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if you find it the most helpful, this will aid future readers with the same problem and let people know that the question has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Line

```
adj = static_cast<List*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(List*)));
```

suggests that **adj** is an array of **List** objects, while line

```
adj[i] = new List();
```

suggests that it is an array of pointers. You should check the definition of **adj**. By the way, the error refers to the latter line.

**Types**

I'll elaborate a little more on the theoretical aspects of the problem, which revolves around the C++ type system.

In C++ every expression has a *type*, known at compile time. The type of *any* expression of the form

```
static_cast<List*>(...)
```

is

```
List *
```

That is, provided that the type of the expression in parenthesis can be statically casted to List *, the compiler will not complain and the final type of the expression will be List *. Function **calloc** returns void * which can be casted to any other pointer; in fact, pointer casts are often only a way to tell the compiler *yes, I know what I'm doing, shut up*. On most platforms all pointer types have the same bit representation, although the standard does not mandate such a thing, hence in principle no machine code needs to be generated to implement such cast.

The type of an expression such as

```
new List()
```

or

```
new List[10]
```

is

```
List *
```

and an instruction that includes such instructions allocates enough space for a **List** object or for 10 list objects and returns a pointer to such space.

You would probably be better off if you replace the line

```
adj = static_cast<List*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(List*)));
```

with

```
adj = new List[n + 1];
```

If **adj** is a pointer type, the type of an expression such as

```
adj[i]
```

or

```
*(adj + i)
```

or even simply

```
*adj
```

is the pointer type *minus* one of its asterisks; that is, if the type of **adj** is

```
List *
```

the type of **adj[i]** is

```
List
```

That is the reason why you get the error at the line **adj[i] = new List()**; it doesn't make sense to assign

```
List *
```

to

```
List
```

The good news, is that if you allocate **adj** with the **new** operator, you probably don't need to create with **new** every single element; when you allocate an array with **new**, all its elements are created and their constructor is automatically invoked by the compiler.

**Possible solution**

Since the rest of your program is aparently correct, you may simply erase the line

```
adj[i] = new List()
```

and everything should work fine. However as *john* noted, your intent is not very clear; you really need to tell us if you want **adj** to be an array of objects

```
List *adj;
```

or an array of pointers

```
List **adj;
```

**Advanced topic**

The practical difference between using the C way

```
adj = static_cast<List*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(List*)));
```

or the C++ way

```
adj = new List[n + 1];
```

Is that the constructor of each of the allocated **List** objects **doesn't** get called with the former method. There are a few applications of pointers in which you may want this to be the case, but in general you shouldn't mix C and C++.

Comment: The other issue (which I also missed) is that `static_cast<List*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(List*)));` and `new List[n + 1]` allocate different amounts of memory. My assumption (and yours) is that the OP meant to write `static_cast<List*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(List)));` but I guess we'll never know.

Comment: Good point, I didn't realize that, thanks. I would recommend the OP to also make sure he understands what **calloc** does.

Answer (score 0):

A hybrid mix of C and C++ is actually going to be harder than pure C++.

In this case the problem seems to be that you have

```
class Graph
{
    ...
    List* adj;
    ...
};
```

so

```
adj[i] = new List();
```

is wrong because `adj[i]` is of type `List` and `new List()` is of type `List*`.

The fix for this is to use *placement new*.

```
#include <new>

new (adj + i) List();
```

This will construct a `List` at address `&adj[i]` which is what you are trying to achieve I think.

But this is advanced C++ and is only necessary because you are trying to write a mix of C and C++. I would ditch the C part as soon as possible.

**EDIT**

OK as refp points out (and I missed) you have

```
adj = static_cast<List*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(List*)));
```

My answer is only correct if that is a mistake and you intended

```
adj = static_cast<List*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(List)));
```

Comment: the use of *placement-new* is **very** incorrect, unless `sizeof(List)` is the same or smaller than `sizeof(List*)` and has the same *alignment*. (ie. no, do not try what has been mentioned above kids) (*note that OP didn't use `sizeof(List)` in his `calloc` but `sizeof(List*)`*).

Comment: what is the purpose of *placement-new*? (to place an object at a specific adress, it doesn't create a pointer at the adress specified and the object somewhere else)

Comment: @refp you could equally ask what is the intent of allocating an array of List* and then assigning to List*. Clearly the OP has issues with pointers.

Comment: OP is complaining about the invalid use of `adj[i]->` further down in his post which leeds me to believe that the OP's mistake is not in `sizeof(List*)`.

Comment: @refp Fair enough, I've stated my assumptions, at present only the OP knows if they are correct or not.